# Getting wider output in PyCharm's built-in console

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, pycharm

I'm relatively new to using the PyCharm IDE, and have been unable to find a way to better shape the output when in a built-in console session. I'm typically working with pretty wide dataframes, that would fit easily across my monitor, but the display is cutting and wrapping them much sooner than needed.

Does anyone know of a setting to change this behavior to take advantage of the full width of my screen?

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to prevent it from wrapping after only a few columns (for example, the column 'ReadmitRate' should be immediately to the right of 'SNFDaysPerSNFCase')

Comment: I don't understand this problem. For me, the console window spans over the full width of the screen. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks. But as far as I see, this doesn't have anything to do with the console width. Do you call `print` multiple times? If yes, you can set the `end` parameter to `""` which suppresses the standard line break.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It appears I was mistaken in thinking that the issue was one in PyCharm (that could be solved, for example, in a setting or preference.) It actually has to do with the console session itself. The console attempts to auto-detect the width of the display area, but when that fails it defaults to 80 characters. This behavior can be overridden with:

```
import pandas as pd
desired_width = 320    
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
```

Where you can of course set the `desired_width` to whatever your display will tolerate.
Thanks to @TidB for the suggestion that my initial concern wasn't focused in the right area.

Comment: Also have to set width for NumPy arrays, see my answer.

Comment: Still seems like an issue with PyCharm console because the output width is correct in Xfce terminal and Terminator. I suspect that explicitly setting Pandas display width might override the default behaviour in other linux terminals.

Answer (score 77):

For me, just setting `'display.width'` wasn't enough in pycharm, it kept displaying in truncated form.

However, adding the option `pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 10)` together with display width worked and I was able to see the whole dataframe printed in the "run" output.

In summary:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
```

Comment: this is the only completely working answer. Thanks @Idodo!

Comment: actually these finalized the problem:
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)

Comment: adding max columns as an option worked for me. Thanks @Idodo

Comment: @alexanderostrikov 's answer worked even better. thank you BOTH for finally fixing this annoying thing for me

Comment: I needed to apply this as well for things to work. I was pulling out my hair with `display.width` not working. Thanks @ldodo.

Answer (score 23):

The answer by `@mattvivier` works nicely when printing Pandas dataframes (thanks!).

However, if you are printing NumPy arrays, you need to set `np.set_printoptions` as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=desired_width)
```

See [docs on NumPy and set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Answer (score 5):

```
def pd_set_df_view_options(max_rows=1000, max_columns=350, display_width=320):

    # Show more than 10 or 20 rows when a dataframe comes back.
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', max_rows) 
    # Columns displayed in debug view
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', max_columns)

    pd.set_option('display.width', display_width)

# run
pd_set_df_view_options(max_rows=1000, max_columns=350, display_width=320)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Contago's answer :

**Universal settings**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


desired_width = 320

## dataframe ##
# increase dataframe print area
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)

# increase no. of df columns displayed
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', n)


## numpy array ##
# increase numpy array print area
np.set_printoptions(linewidth = desired_width)
```

**Context specific (temporary)**

```
# dataframe
with pd.option_context('display.max_columns', 20,
                       'display.width', 320):
    print(df)

# numpy array
with np.printoptions(linewidth=320):
    print(np.array(df))
```