# Pycharm injects new line in output, half way through dataset columns

Tags: pandas, dataset, pycharm

Why would Pycharm put the second half of my dataset on a new line? (see Image) How do I turn this off?

I would like to display my dataset as wide as possible, with no wrapping.

[image]

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628496/getting-wider-output-in-pycharms-built-in-console (possible duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting wider output in PyCharm's built-in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628496/getting-wider-output-in-pycharms-built-in-console)

Answer (score 0):

The console attempts to auto-detect the width of the display area, but when that fails it defaults to 80 characters. This behavior can be overridden with:

`import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)`

please take reference from this stackoverflow
[Getting wider output in PyCharm's built-in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628496/getting-wider-output-in-pycharms-built-in-console)