# How to display all print result in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, display

Whenever I run a huge file that contains several observations (i.e, columns), Pycharm does not show all the observations. The below picture shows only 2 observations whereas I need to display all observations (in my case, there are 10 observations).

How do I solve this?

[image: Screebhot Pycharm Run Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50947606/6914378), you can increase the display width and the amount of columns:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
```